# I am trying to login to my local SQL Server 2017 installed on Windows10 using SSMS using Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server

This is in my personal system. When I try to connect to SSMS via windows auth, I am unable to login and I am receiving the following error. When I have installed the server I have selected only windows auth mode(I guess). I have made few changes in configuration manager like enabling TCP/IP and named pipes but of no use. Can anyone please help me here? I am attaching the image for the reference.

[image: reference]

Comment: It is SSMS18.5 by the way

Comment: If you're connecting to the local instance, just use `.` as the server name.

Comment: Do you know that you can copy message texts from SSMS (or any other Windows) dialogs?

Comment: @Larnu I have tried this but nope not in.

Comment: @Arvo TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to ..

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=0&LinkId=20

Comment: Thank you and edit that text into your message then - much better to see and google it :) While setting your SQL server up, did you enter your personal account as administrative one?

Comment: Have you changed your Windows password since installing SQL Server? Try restarting your machine to remove cached credentials.

Comment: @Arvo I did that too, I have searched in google too. I posted a question here to get some help :-)  And yes I used my personal account.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have tried that too. I tried changing the password and restarted the machine. But not able to connect,

Comment: Perhaps you're name is incorrect, and you have a named instance. [See This question](http://expresstechnology.com/knowledgebase/what-is-the-difference-between-named-and-default-instances-in-sql-server/#:~:text=A%20named%20instance%20is%20identified,you%20specify%20an%20instance%20name.) on how to find out.